# Optaplanner Constraint Streams other join types than "inner join"

Tags: java, optaplanner

Is it possible to use other join types than inner join in OptaPlanner Constraint Streams? In my case I need to do a left join.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. See [conditional propagation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsConditionalPropagation) for how to handle situations when something is or is not present.

Comment: Should we consider to support `.leftJoin()` too? That is semantically a combination of `.join()` and `.ifNotExists()` but with the dangerous situation that some of the tuple elements will be null (neither join() nor ifNotExists() suffer from this, because the latter doesn't increase the cardinality of the constraint stream).

Comment: Actually I think this would be a good feature. So I can imagine some constraints where it is relevant to work on a complete list of "the left element" and for example sum up an attribute of the right element id it exists. On the other hand I understand your point that this could bring further complexity because of the null values.

Comment: I would argue that whether a joining fact is missing or not is a very important circumstance, a different branch of a decision tree. As such, for the purposes of scoring, it warrants being represented by a different constraint. (Which is what the ifExists/ifNotExists API allows for.) I am not in favor of mixing these two branches, especially as it means introducing null into the mix.

Comment: I tend to agree with Lukas. But I could be convinced otherwise, with real examples of constraints that clearly benefit from a "left join". @pa92trick Do you have one you can share?

Comment: Yes taking the node/edge example from my other thread.

Nodes: a,b,c,d
Edges: a->b; a->d; b->d

Each node have minimum and maximum stock levels resulting in a deviation (a=-4; b=0; c=+6; d=+1)
Using as fitness function "minimize the deviation in the whole network". When you want to calculate the sum of the deviations at the end of the period (start deviations +/- incoming outgoing items) by joining the edges to the nodes the resulting penalty will not include the stations without edges.

Comment: For a single run of the solver this is maybe not so relevant because the solver cannot do anything when there no edges, but the edges changing from time to time (this is continuous planning example). So later examples are better comparable when the score is from the whole network. I found a workaround with an additional constraint but this would be an example für a left join constraint.